# Should a view be ordering data?

Tags: reactjs, api-design, ecmascript-2016

I have data coming from an API not in order and this is affecting my front-ends ordering, I am thinking what the most correct way to fix this issue is.

Should I be expecting the correct data to come from my api and use that as it is or should I be sorting data on the front-end?

So what I am asking in terms of software practices what's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API should provide a way to sort the data that's being returned. If you sort on the front end, proper pagination becomes nightmarish.

Comment: I agree on what you said, I would add that sometimes depends on how much data you are expecting from and how easy is for you to modify your API to allow ordering (if you can). But in general cases, API should receive some kind of sort params to accomplish that.

Comment: Thanks, what you both have said makes perfect sense and I totally agree